# How do I hide pylint warnings about importing from sister modules?

Tags: python, pylint

*** Edit: I started receiving this warning after upgrading from pylint 1.3 to pylint 1.4.

I am receiving a warning in pylint when importing a module from a "sister module" at the same level, even though the code actually runs properly.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/root
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /folder1
        __init__.py
        test1.py
    /folder2
        __init__.py
        test2.py
```

Contents of main.py:

```
from folder1.test1 import *
from folder2.test2 import *

print "KEY1:", KEY1
print "KEY2:", KEY2
```

Contents of test1.py:

```
KEY1 = "key number one"
```

Contents of test2.py:

```
from folder1.test1 import*

KEY2 = "key 2:" + KEY1
```

When I run "python root/main.py", I get the expected output:

```
KEY1: key number one
KEY2: key 2:key number one
```

But when I run "pylint -E root --disable=print-statement", I receive a warning:

```
************* Module root.folder2.test2
E:  3,18: Undefined variable 'KEY1' (undefined-variable)
```

How can I silence this warning?

Comment: You should avoid relative imports, eg change your 'from folder...' to 'from root.folder...' (pylint should have reported that to you) and see if this fixes the problem

Comment: Actually that causes the code to not work at all. It gives me:
    ImportError: No module named root.folder1.test1

Comment: @camomilk: That's because you're using Python 2.  In Python 3, the import system has changed and your relative imports will not work properly.  You can switch to the Py3k way of doing things with `from __future__ import absolute_import`.  Anyway, I imagine pylint is not pleased with your use of `import *`, which is widely regarded as evil.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe the real issue is that our project depends on python 2.7, while pylint expects python 3.0. Can I tell pylint to expect Python 2.7 conventions? Or is it now fairly useless for a project using Python 2.7?